# CodeIgniter Authentication Library 2011

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am looking for a flexible, easy customized, Userlevel access and secure Authentication library that I can quickly get started with.

I was looking at Stackoverflow and read about a few Authentication libraries but these posts were posted in 2010.

What Authentication library out there should I use? Why?

Comment: Ion Auth and Tank Auth still are the best out there (the former being used IIRC in PyroCms). Until the one I'm developing will be out, of course :)

Comment: What is the main difference between Ion Auth and Tank Auth?

Comment: Ion Auth looks more active (I usually use that, so can't really speak about TankAuth), and I like its coding style more (but it's a matter of preference). Tank Auth makes use of phPass, as a plus though. You should try them both and see their features (almost the same) and which best fits for your needs/style/feeling

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As little i know, TankAuth was missing several features and code fix but it was not updated nor maintained.
So ion_auth is a very good replacement, because it's now maintened (as part of CI based pyrocms).

T.A. is still working i think, but as there are no updates i would say go ION_AUTH

Comment: Does Expression Engine use their own solution?  It's a shame they don't offer it apart from their entire system.

Comment: I have tried out Ion_Auth and I didn't like it. It misses features like recaptcha, etc. I think I am going for TankAuth, But Is it secure?

Answer (score 0):

I am using Ion Auth, but having to extensively modify it to do user level access more detailed than admin and member users and there is no ACL that you would need for a typical web app without modifying the code yourself.

Answer (score 0):

2012 Update:

Personally I've used Ion Auth, Tank Auth, and a couple of other authentication libraries. But honestly most of them are no longer compatible for the latest release of CodeIgniter, and I'd need to spend more time debugging the libraries than to write a new one myself.

However, recently I've came across

[bitauth](https://github.com/danmontgomery/codeigniter-bitauth)

Works perfectly in version 2.1.2, without any sort of debugging required. Clean css which does not mess my normal stylesheets, and easily overridden.

I'd recommend this for anyone who is looking for an authentication library in 2012, as it is still being managed.